# File not found error Google Drive API

Tags: google-drive-api

I am using the Drive REST API to download a file. I am making a GET request using the file id and I get a `file not found exception`.

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "notFound",
    "message": "File not found: xxxxx",
    "locationType": "other",
    "location": "file"
   }
  ],
  "code": 404,
  "message": "File not found: xxxxx"
 }
}
```

I have also generated the apikey and I am using it in my GET request.The file does exist so I am unsure what I am missing here.

Comment: paste the http request/response into your question so we can see what's happening. Ostensibly the message is self explanatory, so I'd suspect the value of the file ID.

Comment: 404 is resource not found. Most probably it is something with url is not correct. Try to access the file in browser if you are able to get the file or not. You can also try this in the API explorer : https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get#try-it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is resolved. I wasn't providing the correct access_token when making the GET request for file metadata. I regenerated the authorization code, access_token and my code is working now.

Comment: refreshing the token didn't work for me. I can see the files but I can't download them.

Comment: Hi @user2676491, it would be nice if you shared how you resolved this for other people with similar issues

Answer (score 11):

Make sure **scopes** are corrects

```
var url = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
access_type: 'offline',
scope: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata'
  ]
});
```

*Drive API declares the following scopes. Select which ones you want to grant to APIs Explorer.*

- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
  View and manage the files in your Google Drive
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata
  View and manage its own configuration data in your Google Drive
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file
  View and manage Google Drive files and folders that you have opened or created with this app
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata
  View and manage metadata of files in your Google Drive
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly
  View metadata for files in your Google Drive
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.photos.readonly
  View the photos, videos and albums in your Google Photos
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly
  View the files in your Google Drive
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.scripts
  Modify your Google Apps Script scripts' behaviour

Sorce: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/drive/v3/drive.files.get

Answer (score 9):

In my case, I simply had not given access to the folder to my service account. Simply sharing it via the web interface solved the problem.

##### What email address to use:

Check the email address of your service account here:

https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts?project=NAME_OF_PROJECT&supportedpurview=project

The email address will look like this:

```
name-of-service-account@name-of-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

Comment: This was my issue too, I didn't see it documented anywhere, thanks!

Comment: my issue too. Life saver, god bless you kind sir.

Answer (score 7):

If you are getting a response like this:

```
<HttpError 404 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/REDACTED_FILE_ID/copy?alt=json returned "File not found: REDACTED_FILE_ID.". Details: "[{'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'notFound', 'message': 'File not found: REDACTED_FILE_ID.', 'locationType': 'parameter', 'location': 'fileId'}]">
```

And the fileId points to a file on a Shared Drive, you'll need to include supportsSharedDrives=true in your request parameters.

Google provides more detail on this in their [Implement shared drive support](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/enable-shareddrives)  article.

Here's a small example with Python for creating a copy:

```py
googledrive = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

copy_response = googledrive.files().copy(
    fileId=TEMPLATE_SPREADSHEET_ID,
    body={
        "parents": [
            report_folder_id,
        ],
        'title': report_title
    },
    supportsAllDrives=True
).execute()
```

In order to run that, you'll want to mix it into the example code from the [Python Quickstart for Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python).

Comment: `supportsAllDrives=True` mattered for me because I was trying to get/update a *shared* file.

Comment: @ZachYoung that was exactly my experience. I spent ages spinning my wheels wondering why my requests were failing before realizing I needed that set to True.

Comment: Wish I'd found this 2 hours ago, exactly my problem as well!

Answer (score 6):

I would check to see if the file you are trying to retrieve the metadata for is part of a team drive; if it is then you have to set `supportsTeamDrives=True` in the request.

Comment: supportsTeamDrives is deprecated in v3, see the supportsAllDrives answer

Answer (score 3):

I got to this question because I was getting a "File not found" error when using the `update` method.

I was using this line in Python to execute the method:

```py
files_res.update(fileId=f_id, body={"name": f_name}).execute()
```

I could list the ***shared*** file and its parent fine, but update failed, no matter what the scope with this error:

```json
...
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "notFound",
    "message": "File not found: 1YqV...",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": "fileId"
   }
  ],
  "code": 404,
...
```

I added the `supportsAllDrives=True` param to the method and it worked:

```py
files_res.update(fileId=f_id, body={"name": f_name}, supportsAllDrives=True).execute()
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was using the file `client_secret.json` that I had created with the gmail address I use all the time, but I was creating the credentials with another e-mail.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem but it's a different story.
In fact, I created a service account & generate a secret in json format.
the service account generate a random address mail which is the client_email in your secret json.
While trying to upload to a given folder I get back the error:

> GaxiosError: File not found: 1dQqKNFCSvf3pIvXXXXXX.

Where the id ***1dQqKNFCSvf3pIvXXXXXX*** is the parent folder id.

After some investigation email so the service account can reach the folder and put files inside.